# How can I get Apache to stop showing files and directories on the web page?

Tags: 22.04, apache2, configuration, webserver, nas

I am building an *Apache* server to work as a http file directory for an application. All is done and working except I can't seem to hide the directories seen when inputting the IP address into a web browser.

I have tried changing: `Options -Indexes;` and `Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks;` in the `a..2.conf`, `sites-avai.../sites`. And so on but to no avail.

Edit:
Ok so what I am seeing when inputting IP address in browser is *webfsd*, not *Apache*. How do I change this behavior? I have uninstalled and stopped *webfsd*.

Comment: Okay So ive now figured out that what I am seeing is actually webfsd and not Apache.

Comment: Is your question about Apache or webfsd?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to not show the index or list of files when a user visits that directory, you can create a file named `index.html` in that directory.

You can fill the file with whatever html you want but the purpose here will be just as a placeholder and to hide the index list of files.

For example, if the directory is `/var/www/html/` then you would create the following file:

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/index.html
```

and you could put something like the following to show the words "hello world" instead of the list of files:

```
<html><p>hello world</p></html>
```

When you are done editing the file, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Also, don't forget to reload Apache to apply the changes:

```
sudo systemctl graceful apache2
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Now when someone visits that directory, they will see "hello world" instead of the index list of files. Of course, you can change hello world to whatever you want but the point is that the user doesn't need to load the `index.html` file in the URL, they only need to visit the directory that contains `index.html` and the `index.html` will show instead of the list of files.

Comment: Of course, if you have a webpage to show (as it sounds like you do from your question), you could simply name whatever html page you want to show as `index.html` and put that in the directory that is currently showing the list of files when you input the IP so that this page will show by default when visiting that directory instead of the list of files.

Comment: It should be noted that users will still be able to access the files in that directory if they input the full path along with the exact name of the file into their browser. However, they will not be able to see a list of those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Webfsd to disable directory listing by using the `-j` option.

Start Webfsd with directory listing disabled:

```
webfsd -j /opt/webfolder
```

The `-j` option tells Webfsd to deny directory listings, and it will return a "Access denied" error when trying to access directory listings.